In Open Air – fill the blanks
This is part 76 of the puzzle series Around the World in Many Days. Each part is solvable on its own.

Dear Puzzling,
Today I have travelled in open air, under the scorching sun, to see a small selection from the staggering amount of ancient tombs and temples found in this area. Can you guess where I am?
Love, Gladys.
Warm-up questions
1. ____ world city in ____
2. Apollo module's ____-v: 2.22 ____metres per…?
3. Anglo-____  War ____
4. ____ Rain : Rose :: ____ in the Jar : ?
5. ____ or ____
6. Former ____s player ____
7. Rio ____ : Wayne :: ____ Rwanda : ?
8. In ____, ____ = in Ontario, ?
((Real)) questions
9. ____ near ((____))
10. Stereotypical ((____)) for ____
11. ((____)) vision : Superman :: ____location : ?
12. ____ with three ((____))s
13.____, to ((____))
Answers
BRITAIN
CHAPLIN
CHEADLE
CORDILLERA BLANCA
DAD
DANCE
DAREDEVIL
GIRLFRIEND
HETFIELD
MUMBAI
MUSSINA
PLUS FOURS
SECOND

Gladys will return in Middle of Nowhere.

Gladys is in:

 Luxor, in Upper Egypt.

To solve this puzzle, first note...

 ...that there are exactly 26 blanks. This should set the mind immediately thinking about letters of the alphabet, of which there are 26 in English. Moreover, if we are looking to fill the gaps with 26 words (rather than letters) then it is natural to wonder whether these words might be those of the NATO phonetic alphabet...

 With this in mind, noticing that clue 7 looks like it could be making reference to two movies - Rio BRAVO and HOTEL Rwanda, with an answer of 'CHEADLE' from the answer list - this makes us think we're onto something and should try filling all the others...

The gaps should be filled like so...

 1. ALPHA world city in INDIA = MUMBAI

An 'alpha world city' is a city that links major economic regions and states into the world economy.

 2. Apollo module's DELTA-v: 2.22 KILOmetres per…? = SECOND

Delta-v = change in velocity

 3. Anglo-ZULU War VICTOR = BRITAIN

 4. NOVEMBER Rain : Rose :: WHISKEY in the Jar : ? = HETFIELD

Lead singers of these songs.

 5. FOXTROT or TANGO = DANCE

 6. Former YANKEEs player MIKE = MUSSINA

 7. Rio BRAVO : Wayne :: HOTEL Rwanda : ? = CHEADLE

Lead actors in these movies.

 8. In QUEBEC, PAPA = in Ontario, ? = DAD

In French-speaking Quebec, the word for 'father' is 'papa'; in English-speaking Ontario, it would be 'dad'.

 9. SIERRA near ((LIMA)) = CORDILLERA BLANCA

A mountain range in Peru.

 10. Stereotypical ((UNIFORM)) for GOLF = PLUS FOURS

 11. ((XRAY)) vision : Superman :: ECHOlocation : ? = DAREDEVIL

Superpowers of superheroes.

 12. CHARLIE with three ((OSCAR))s = CHAPLIN

 13. JULIET, to ((ROMEO)) = GIRLFRIEND

In the Shakespeare play...

To extract the final answer...

 ...focus on the NATO terms in double-parentheses in the '((Real)) questions' section. In order, these are LIMA, UNIFORM, XRAY, OSCAR and ROMEO, which spell out the answer LUXOR!


Every clue can be filled in by...

 two letters of the NATO phonetic alphabet.

Here are the filled-in clues, with their answers:

1. ALPHA world city in INDIA = MUMBAI
2. Apollo module's DELTA-v: 2.22 KILOmeters per ? = SECOND
3. Anglo-ZULU War VICTOR = BRITISH
4. NOVEMBER Rain : Rose :: WHISKEY in the Jar : ? = HETFIELD
5. TANGO or FOXTROT = DANCE
6. Former YANKEEs player MIKE = MUSSINA
7. Rio BRAVO: Wayne :: HOTEL Rwanda : ? = CHEADLE
8. In QUEBEC, PAPA = in Ontario, ? = DAD

9. SIERRA near (LIMA) = CORDILLERA BLANCA
10. Stereotypical (UNIFORM) for GOLF = PLUS FOURS
11. (X-RAY) vision : Superman :: ECHOlocation : ? = DAREDEVIL
12. CHARLIE with three (OSCAR)s = CHAPLIN
13. JULIET, to (ROMEO) = GIRLFRIEND\

The parenthesised words spell out...

LIMA UNIFORM X-RAY OSCAR ROMEO = LUXOR, Egypt, which is where you are right now!


Snap! (Except for the ordering of #5!)
